# Can you choose your faction during the campaign?

Tags: titanfall

Titanfall has two campaigns, one for each faction, the IMC Campaign and the Militia Campaign. Is there anyway to choose your faction before matchmaking? It it helps, I've completed both campaigns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously can't (at least I haven't found any selection mechanism so far).

Basically, the first playthrough you'll be matched into one of the teams randomly (or based on some unknown formula). The second playthrough you'll be matched with the other team you're still missing completion. From then on you're matched wherever there is some room.

It's far from being perfect, but given the nature of the campaign and how the "unlocks" work (order of unlocked titan hulls is the same, no matter which faction you've played first), I'd consider it sufficient.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect; you can get assigned to any faction on your first playthrough.

Comment: Are you sure? So the very first selection might be purely random, but you'll stick to that faction till you've completed the playthrough? Can't test it for obvious reasons. :)

Comment: I was assigned to IMC on my first playthrough but then I had to stick to it. Still it's kinda stupid that I can't choose my faction. Especially if I want to replay a mission for a specific side...

Comment: Okay, so seems to be random then. Editing the answer.

Comment: This will make getting the achievement for winning all the campaign missions very fiddly.

Comment: Are you sure? When I clicked a mission I didn't complete for one faction, I always joined that faction. Coincidence or intentional?

Comment: @Mario When you say didn't complete, do you mean you didn't win?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter whether you win or lose. You'll still progress (and the mission will be considered complete). It's only important that you stay for the full duration (i.e. don't quite before the end of the round).

Comment: @Mario In fact, ignore that comment, I know what you meant now.

Comment: @peper757 once you've completed both campaigns you can choose what level to play but not what side - you'll get assigned to whatever side is free, but if you get the wrong one you can leave the lobby and try again. I had to restart the first mission about 20 times to get a) Militia side and b) Team not full of lvl 1 players so we could win it in order to complete _Elite Militia Pilot_.